# Speed is very slow Apache, PHP, MySQL, Vagrant, Debian

Tags: php, performance, apache2, debian, vagrant

I am using vagrant, its very slow, i tried every solution suggested at the internet, it doesn't help. So I decided trying to track the problem, inside the server.

Server uses apache, mysql, memcached, php.

When I use top, I see that server is not loaded at all. Cpu is maximum 1.5% when I do query, but it still takes 20 minutes to load one page.

What i noticed that all the processes are running under priority 20 - nice 20. And apache process is appears once every 5 seconds.

I am wondering what doesn't allow it use up to 100% of cpu and memory. Memory usage is also low, its 238 MB out of 4GB for apache and 331 mb for MYSQL here how it looks:

3441 www  20   0  231m  41m 4848 S   1.3  1.1   0:14.68 apache2

So the page loads for 15 minutes at the moment..

I executed some commands to give you more details:

admin$ vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0      0 3599460   5140  89516    0    0    21     1  161  352  0  1 99  0

admin$ iotop
Total DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init [2]
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
    6 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
    7 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/0]
    8 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuset]
    9 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [khelper]
   10 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kdevtmpfs]
   11 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [netns]

The process is still running it only gives bigger then zero once in a while. like 1.5 kb

user# dstat
You did not select any stats, using -cdngy by default.
----total-cpu-usage---- -dsk/total- -net/total- ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai hiq siq| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw 
  0   1  99   0   0   0|  30k   18k|   0     0 |   0     0 | 161   351 
  0   1  98   0   0   1|   0     0 |2073B 1216B|   0     0 | 267   543 
  0   1  99   0   0   0|   0     0 |1640B  710B|   0     0 | 225   460 
  1   1  98   0   0   0|   0     0 |1793B  762B|   0     0 | 257   537 
  1   1  98   0   0   0|   0     0 |1209B  729B|   0     0 | 174   349 
  0   1  99   0   0   0|   0     0 |1463B  534B|   0     0 | 254   520 
  0   1  99   0   0   0|   0    24k|1718B  689B|   0     0 | 244   488

Seems like it doesn't user resources, why?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is related to file IO, consider checking out [this resource](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html) and the [accompanying vagrant documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html) for using NFS.